# A table with 2 foreign keys referencing the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have a table with 2 forign keys referencing the same table. How would like print out the join contents? I'm using SQLite

TableA

```
S.NO  Col1   Col2
1    | a   |  b
2    | f   |  g
3    | d   |  e
```

TableB

```
S.NO  Col3 
a    | apple   
b    | ball
f    | frog
g    | grape
d    | dog
e    | eat
```

How do i print out the following?

```
S.NO |Col1  | Col2 | Col3| Col4
1    | a    |apple |  b  | ball
2    | f    |frog  |  g  | grape
3    | d    |dog   |  e  | eat
```

I tried

```
SELECT TableA.Col1, TableB.Col3, TableA.Col1 
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col3
AND TableA.Col2 = TableB.Col3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: One does not have to have FKs to join. It is necessary & sufficient to know the table meanings. What matters to you here is that certain columns are equal between certain tables. Aliases let you us the same table's value multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two inner joins will do:

```
select 
    a.sno, a.col1, b1.col3, a.col2, b2.col3
  from tablea a
  join tableb b1 on b1.sno = a.col1
  join tableb b2 on b2.sno = a.col2
```

Note `tableb` is joined twice. In this case you need to give it a different alias each time: `b1` and `b2`. Otherwise there would be no clear way of referencing columns from each one.